# Converting a shapefile to .sqlite using Python

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, convert, sqlite

I am trying to convert a shapefile to SQLite file in QGIS 3.26 using Python.

Here is my code:

```
def convert_to_sqlite(self):
    input_shp = QgsVectorLayer("C:\shapeFile\BMR_Zones_Corrected_519.shp","polygon","ogr")
    print(input_shp.isValid())
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(input_shp,"C:\shapeFile\BMR_Zones_Corrected_519.sqlite","UTF-8",input_shp.crs(),"SQLite")
```

This is the error I am facing:

```
warning:C:\Users/MTTUSER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Network_Processing\ABTDModel.py:477: DeprecationWarning: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat() is deprecated

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(input_shp,"C:\shapeFile\BMR_Zones_Corrected_519.gpkg","UTF-8",input_shp.crs(),"GPKG")
           
traceback: File "C:\Users/MTTUSER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Network_Processing\ABTDModel.py", line 602, in run
result = self.dlg.exec_()
File "C:\Users/MTTUSER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Network_Processing\ABTDModel.py", line 477, in convert_to_sqlite
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(input_shp,"C:\shapeFile\BMR_Zones_Corrected_519.gpkg","UTF-8",input_shp.crs(),"GPKG")
```

Comment: Why pyqgis? You can use geopandas. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141818/insert-geopandas-geodataframe-into-spatialite-database and https://www.giacomodebidda.com/posts/export-a-geodataframe-to-spatialite/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
shape = r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/subway.shp'
output = r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/subway.sqlite'
vl = QgsVectorLayer(shape, 'temp')
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "SQLite"
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(vl, output, QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), options)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me.